# How to create child PDF bookmarks in index for each index letter

Tags: pdf, indexing, bookmarks

I have a rather lengthy index to my document. I have a bookmark so I can quickly get to the index, but I'd like child bookmarks for each letter of the alphabet so I can go to that section of the index directly. I am currently using the `imakeidx` package for generating my index, but I couldn't find any package options allowing me to create the child bookmarks.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
% File \jobname.mst is overwritten, if package filecontents is loaded!
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
  \belowpdfbookmark{#1}{#1}%
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Hello\index{hello} world\index{world}!

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\indexname}{index}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Makeindex automatically looks for a file `\jobname.mst` for style definitions. There the headings can be configured. The example inserts macro `\IndexHeading`, which creates a bookmark below the current level.