# How to provide a navigation line at the start of the index with links to each group that is present in the index?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, links

(**Context:** Here is considered an electronic (PDF) version of a document.)

When an index becomes lengthy, a table of contents entry or a bookmark leading to its first page is not enough because the reader may need to go to the next page a large and unpredictable number of times.

What could be helpful are child bookmarks for each index letter as discussed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331961/18401) but would be useless for a reader who doesn't notice bookmarks or at least hidden child bookmarks.

A more helpful feature would be what `glossaries` package provides with its `listhypergroup` style: a navigation line at the start of the glossary with links to each group that is present in the glossary (see "B | F" line in the MWE below). I know `glossaries` provides index feature but, for some reasons (mainly custom `.xdy` index style files), I need to use custom indexing packages such as `imakeidx`.

Do you see how to provide a navigation line at the start of the index with links to each group that is present in the index (the corresponding code in `glossaries` package is quite ugly :)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%
\newglossaryentry{foo}%
{%
  name={foo},%
  description={Foo}%
}
\newglossaryentry{bar}%
{%
  name={bar},%
  description={Bar}
}
%
\begin{document}
\Gls{foo} and \gls{bar}.
%
\printglossary[style=listhypergroup]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to switch on the headings (as in the linked question). This can be used to set the hyperlink targets and provide a letter group heading:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
\end{filecontents}

\makeindex

\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{\item\hypertarget{idx:#1}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Foo\index{foo}. Bar\index{bar}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This gives each letter group the target name `idx:`*letter*. For example `idx:F` for the `F` letter group. The formatting for the heading is quite simplistic but is just for illustration.

The next thing is the navigation at the start of the index, which is a bit more complicated. Let's provide the command `\indexnavigation`, which will contain the navigation links. This needs to go in the index preamble, but how this is done depends on the indexing package that you're using. For example, with `imakeidx`, this can be done with `\indexprologue{\indexnavigation}`, whereas with `makeidx` the `theindex` environment needs to be redefined.

To keep things simple, I'm just going to add `\indexnavigation` after `\begin{theindex}`, which won't span a multicolumn index but it's just for illustration:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\indexnavigation\n"
\end{filecontents}
```

The problem now is that not all the letter groups may be available. (In this example, there are only the two groups `B` and `F`.) However, there's no way of telling which groups are available until the index has been processed, so this means saving information to the `.aux` file (which is what `glossaries` does in the MWE you supplied).

The `\indexheading` command can be adapted to write the required information to the `.aux` file:

```
\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{\item\hypertarget{idx:#1}{\textbf{#1}}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@indexgroup{idx:#1}{#1}}%
}
```

This means that the `.aux` file will now contain:

```
\@indexgroup{idx:B}{B}
\@indexgroup{idx:F}{F}
```

This new internal command `\@indexgroup` needs to be defined to add the letter group to `\indexnavigation`. The `etoolbox` package makes things a bit easier:

```
\newcommand*{\@indexgroup}[2]{%
  \ifdefempty\indexnavigation
  {\gdef\indexnavigation{\hyperlink{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}}%
  {\gappto\indexnavigation{ \textbar\ \hyperlink{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}}%
}
```

Note that the global versions `\gdef` and `\gappto` are required.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\item\\indexnavigation\n"
\end{filecontents}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\indexnavigation}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{\item\hypertarget{idx:#1}{\textbf{#1}}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@indexgroup{idx:#1}{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@indexgroup}[2]{%
  \ifdefempty\indexnavigation
  {\gdef\indexnavigation{\hyperlink{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}}%
  {\gappto\indexnavigation{ \textbar\ \hyperlink{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Foo\index{foo}. Bar\index{bar}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Note that this requires two LaTeX runs after the index has been created by `makeindex` to ensure the navigation links are up to date.

[image: image of index with navigation line]

Comment: These nice tricks should be provided as a package! :)